# Python passing variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to figure out why I cannot pass my two variables to get the API call to work. I know the API call works when I put static name/key in their places. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import httplib

#Print my list to choose from. 
servers = {'server1.com':'#######','server2.com':'######'}
for server, key in servers.items():
    print server

#User chooses which node, it should print what they chose, then store into 
variable to send for API Post. 
node = raw_input("Which node would you like to check Network Bytes for? ")
if node == server:
    print serves.item(server)
    print servers.item(key)
    box = servers.item(server)
    api = servers.item(key)


headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 
'Authorization': 'GetData apikey=' + api}
body = r"""{
  "cycle": "5min",
  "from": 0,
  "metric_category": "net",
  "metric_specs": [
    {
      "name": "bytes_in"
    }
  ],
  "object_ids": [
    0
  ],
  "object_type": "device",
  "until": 0
}
"""
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(box)
conn.request('POST', '/api/v1/metrics', headers=headers, body=body)
resp = conn.getresponse()
print resp.read()
```

Comment: `print serves.item(server)` what does this return? if it's a typo for `servers` same question for the next print line. `dict` don't have an item function...

Comment: I get my initial dictionary list to view and choose from but after I chose it doesnt print anything and exits with error code 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the json module to translate the Python dict (headers) into a json object.  Although they are similar the syntax is subtly different.

The other issue I see here is that `server` is undefined when you are testing for it.  You created `server` in the `for` loop, but it's fallen out of scope before you `if node == server:`.  Perhaps you could replace that part with:

```
#User chooses which node, it should print what they chose, then store into 
variable to send for API Post. 
box = raw_input("Which node would you like to check Network Bytes for? ")
api = servers.get(node, None):
print "box/node:", box
print "  api   :", api
```

Comment: where api is defined servers is an undefined error. and where node is its expecting an end of statement. Do I need to indent?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop logic is incorrect, as it iterates the dictionary but always will hold the last k,v pair.

```
servers = {'server1.com':'#######','server2.com':'######'}
for server, key in servers.items():
    print server
```

That basically means every time this runs, it will end holding the same value from the dict. You **shouldn't use `server / key` variables outside of your loop**, it's not right and you can expect strange behavior

But the issue resides in your dict retrieval

```
if node == server:
    **print serves.item(server)** # there's a typo here
    print servers.item(key)
    box = servers.item(server)
    api = servers.item(key)
```

If you want to get the value of a key from a dict, use `servers.get(server)` or `servers[server]`.

And I'm not sure why are you checking `if node == server`? you can eliminate that and just ask for node directly from servers dict: `box = servers.get(node)`

Comment: Thanks I have moved that around and now I get the api key, but then None after it. How was the node name and api key flipped?

Comment: That's becuase node is your key. try using `node` instead of box, and `api = servers.get(node)` should work